# Representing a chessboard in Haskell

Tags: haskell, chess

I'm trying to implement a function in Haskell that returns a list containing all possible moves for the player who's up. The function's only argument is a String composed of an actual state of the board (in [Forsyth-Edwards Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) ) followed by the moving player(b/w).

Notation example : rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w (starting board state)

A move is transmitted as a string of the form [origin]-[destination]. The destination is always a position of the form [column][row], where the lower left square is called a1 and the upper right square is called h8. A move would be for example the move "b3-c4". (no castling/En-passant).

In Java I would use a 2d Array for the Board, but in Haskell I can't find a similar solution (I'm new to functional programming).

**What would be a good way/data structure to represent the chess board in?**

Comment: https://github.com/OlivierNicole/haskell-chess/blob/master/ChessBoard.hs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two primary options for storing a board state. The first is a 2D list of `Maybe`, where a piece would be represented as, e.g. `Just $ Piece Black King` and a blank square would be represented as `Nothing`. This optimizes determining if a square is occupied over listing where pieces are (which might be important if you plan to add rendering later):

```hs
type Board = Vector (Vector (Maybe Piece))

data Piece = Piece { color :: Color
                   , type  :: PieceType }
```

The second option is to store a list of pieces and their locations. This implementation is faster to enumerate the locations of all pieces, but slower to check if there is a piece on a particular square:

```
type Pieces = [Placement]

type Placement = { position :: Position
                 , piece    :: Piece }

data Position = 
    Pos { rank :: Int
        , file :: Int }
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Piece = 
    Piece { color :: Color
          , ptype :: PieceType }
    deriving Show
```

EDIT: It's worth noting that with an 8x8 grid and a maximum of 32 pieces on the board, the performance hit either way is going to be minimal unless you're doing a lot of calculations.

Answer (score 1):

[`Data.Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Vector.html), has constant time lookup by index.

A chessboard can be represented as a `Vector (Vector (Maybe Piece))`. To define `Piece`, see [ADTs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type)

Comment: I can’t use Vector (only default libraries in Haskell-project limitation). Maybe Data.Array may be an alternative

Comment: Sure thing. GHC haskell provides [GHC.Arr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-Arr.html#t:Array).